# Office 365 AD Authentication with ADAL: missing parameter 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, office365, adal

I'm trying to authenticate in Microsoft Office 365 Azure AD. For the purpose I'm using [Microsoft ADAL library for Objective-C](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) version 1.0. Here is a sample code:

```
ADAuthenticationError *error;
ADAuthenticationContext *authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/...." error:&error];

[authContext acquireTokenWithResource:@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/..."
                     clientId: @"AAAAAA-AAAA-AAAAA-AAAA-AAAAA";
                  redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://localhost:11111"];
                       userId:nil
         extraQueryParameters:@"client_secret=AAAAABBBBBCCCCC"
              completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {
                  if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status){
                      NSLog(@"%@", result.error.errorDetails);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"%@", result.accessToken);
                  }
}];
```

I get

> Error -- AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

Answer (score 0):

ADAL for ObjC only works for public clients, which do not use secrets - and in any case, adding it via extraqueryparameters wouldn't help. How did you register your application in Azure AD? I suspect you might have registered it as a web app (which is a confidential client, requiring client creds when requesting tokens) while it needs to be registered as a native client.